# Yammer API limiting of my request to 5 Requests per minute

Tags: yammer

I can't seem to get the Yammer API to allow more then 5 Requests / Minute. So i have put 6 seconds delay in each request.

But the API page says I should be able to get:
API calls are subject to rate limiting. Exceeding any rate limits will result in all endpoints returning a status code of 429 (Too Many Requests). Rate limits are per user per app. There are four rate limits:

Autocomplete: 10 requests in 10 seconds.

Messages: 10 requests in 30 seconds.

Notifications: 10 requests in 30 seconds.

All Other Resources: 10 requests in 10 seconds.

Comment: Are you getting a `429` error on the 6th request?

Answer (score 0):

We found a bug in the api_messages_controller that was doubling the request count because of a before filter.​ A fix went out so you should be good now.